# OpenCVのCUDAによるCSBPとBPのサンプルコードが動作しない

Tags: opencv, cuda

現在OpenCVのCUDA用ライブラリを利用してステレオマッチングを行おうとしています。

そこでOpenCV付属のサンプルコード（[https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/opencv3/+/master/samples/gpu/stereo_match.cppと同じもの](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/opencv3/+/master/samples/gpu/stereo_match.cpp%E3%81%A8%E5%90%8C%E3%81%98%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE)）を動作させようとしているのですが、BMは正しく動作しているものの、CSBPとBPでは灰色の画面が表示されるだけで、深度の様なものは表示されません、サンプルの画像にはtsukubaを使用しています。

実行時のコマンドライン引数は次の通りです。[--right right.bmp --left left.bmp --method CSBP --ndisp 64]

ndispに関しては何回かいじっているのですが一向に変化がありません。
何かご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら教えていただけると助かります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

同じところで詰まっていましたが、視差画像を表示する直前に

```
cuda::drawColorDisp(d_disp, d_disp, p.ndisp);
```

を追加したら動くようになりました。何故これで動くのかは分かっていません。

---

I have the same problem.
I add cuda::drawColorDisp(d_disp, d_disp, p.ndisp); before showing disparity image

It works for me. But I don't know why.